# Uncharted Golden Abyss : What is the location of Chapter 14?

Tags: uncharted-golden-abyss

In Uncharted Golden Abyss, during chapters 2-12, the action is located in a south american counrty's jungle (presumably Panama).
Chapter 13 is a cut-scene located in the mansion of Chase's grandfather, in which there are talks about the Visigoths.
Then the action skips to an island in chapter 14, but I did not get where it is located.
Chase points to the map mentioning a place called "Casca Vieja" at [this moment](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZlwRF1BOYU&t=4m52s) in the cut-scene.
Where is it supposed to be ?